# showAsAction="withText" отображает только иконку

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Собственно, не могу понять почему отображает только иконку. Текст отображает только при long-тапе по `menuItem`-y.

Вот разметка менюшки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/usersCount"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_outline_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/users_count" />

</menu>
```

Comment: А если без always то в три точки прячется? А если заменить always на ifRoom? А в landscape тоже не работает? А то пишут, что текст может не отображаться если места не хватает.

Comment: Да, без always прячет в точки. Уже тоже вычитал что android автоматически определяет показывать или нет. Видимо от разрешения экрана зависит..

Comment: Я что-то помню такое, там вроде в land будет показываться. Не от разрешения зависит походу а это просто условие для land, но в документации по этому поводу я не нашел такого, поэтому это баг. 
Получается, что для портретной ориентации или картинка или текст. 
Можно обойти это и навязать к item layout, но я не делала этого, поэтому всё)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в пространстве имен - android или app. В вашем случае поменяйте `app` на `android`.

```
app:showAsAction="always|withText" --> android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

Пространство имен зависит от того используете ли вы в проекте библиотеку  `support.V7.appcompact`

В библиотеке v7 appcompat атрибут `showAsAction` не входит в пространство имен `android`.

Comment: Да, я использую эту библиотеку. Менять пробовал тоже, не помогло(

Comment: Activity какой класс наследует AppCompatActivity или Activity?