# Android, toolbar не отображает иконки с именем

Tags: java, android, icon, toolbar

Делаю все, как нужно, но почему то не показывает иконку вместе с текстом. По отдельности показывает и то и другое. А вместе никак - выходит только иконка. Помогите!
menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.detailLeader">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/userNameMenuItem"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Check"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

</menu>
```

Скрин:
[image: скрин]

Comment: [Говорят](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32350279/3212712), что это возможно только в landscape ориентации экрана или есть создать свою разметку для элемента меню

Comment: нет, она подходит и до портретной ориентации

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505832/showasaction-withtext-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83 Задавался таким же вопросом, и насколько я понял это баг. В документации сказано, что система "смотрит" есть ли свободное место в тулбаре, и если есть, то отображает текст. На практике отобразила только на планшете

Answer (score 2):

Есть другой выход - использовать кастомный тулбар, наследник `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, подробнее о его использовании уже писали на SO. Вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/2679651).

По сути, это обычная группа. Туда можно засунуть все, что угодно: кнопки, картинки, текст и т.п.